# SSH could Not Resolve Hostname in bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform

I have deployed a project on AWS using terraform and I am trying to use a script to make it easier to ssh into the EC2 instance that I am using.

I have a terraform output called `host` which contains the public dns for the EC2 instance and an output called `host_ssh_key` which contains the private key.

The bash script I am using is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

tmp_ssh_file="$(mktemp)"

terraform output host_ssh_key > $tmp_ssh_file

chmod 400 $tmp_ssh_file

ssh -i $tmp_ssh_file ubuntu@$(terraform output host)
```

When I try to run this script using `./ssh-host.sh` I get the following error:

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-x.amazonaws.com": nodename nor servname provided, or not known` (without the `x`s)

However when I dump the key to a file and use that with the hostname from the error message I can connect to it fine e.g.

```
terraform output host_ssh_key > private_key.pem
chmod 400 private_key.pem
ssh -i private_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-x.amazonaws.com
```

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Or how to fix it?

Comment: If you redirect the output to a file, what happens if you use `ubuntu@$(cat filename)`?

Comment: No, I mean `terraform output host > test` then `ssh -i $tmp_ssh_file ubuntu@$(cat test)`

Comment: You could also check the `test` file with a hex dump to see if there are any non-printing characters.

Comment: Ah yes, I realised what you meant after I wrote my silly response  looking at the file it was because it was wrapping it in quotes - which also didn't look out of place in the error message. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Silly me, I just did my own `ssh` to an unknown host, and didn't notice that the error message doesn't have quotes.

Comment: I was going deep into ssh configs to see if it was somehow being resolved some other way - it is always the simple things.

Comment: Use `umask 0277` **before** creating key instead of using `chmod 400` **after**!!!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking back at this later the issue was that terraform was wrapping the output in double quotes `"` to resolve the issue I amended the final line to be:

```sh
ssh -i $tmp_ssh_file ubuntu@$(terraform output --raw host)
```